# Open file by name then perform actions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently creating files using `drive.makeCopy(Objects[i][1]);` where Objects is the name of the various files I want to make from a template.

The script works fine in making these files from a template however after each one has been made I would like to open the new file, hide some sheets in it and to set its permissions.  The addresses for the permissions are held in `Objects[i][3]` but I cannot work out how to open these new files, then make the changes accordingly and then close the file.

Comment: see spreadsheetApp.openByX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by drive.MakeCopy() you are referring to File.MakeCopy().  This is easy, the MakeCopy function returns the File object it has created. You can then set permission this File object using functions such as addEditor(), addViewer(), setSharing(), etc.

So if Objects[i][3] contained the email address of someone who should be able to edit the new file, then you could do:

```
   var new_file = drive.makeCopy(Objects[i][1]);
   new_file.addEditor(Objects[i][3]);
```

You don't really need to "Close" the file after working with it, Apps Script takes care of this automatically.

See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addEditor(String)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setSharing(Access,Permission)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file